# How do you use multiple arguments in {} when using the .format() method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, string-formatting, string.format

I want a table in python to print like this:

[image]

Clearly, I want to use the .format() method, but I have long floats that look like this: `1464.1000000000001` I need the floats to be rounded, so that they look like this: `1464.10` (always two decimal places, even if both are zeros, so I can't use the round() function).

I can round the floats using `"{0:.2f}".format("1464.1000000000001")`, but then they do not print into nice tables.

I can put them into nice tables by doing `"{0:>15}.format("1464.1000000000001")`, but then they are not rounded.

Is there a way to do both? Something like `"{0:>15,.2f}.format("1464.1000000000001")`?

Comment: Almost there: `"{0:>15.2f}".format(1464.1000000000001)` is probably what you want.

Comment: Could you not use `round()` inside of `format()?`

Comment: Lots of practical examples at https://pyformat.info/ (next to the [standard Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were almost there, just remove the comma (and pass in a float number, not a string):

```
"{0:>15.2f}".format(1464.1000000000001)
```

See the [*Format Specification Mini-Language* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> ```
> format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
> fill        ::=  <any character>
> align       ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
> sign        ::=  "+" | "-" | " "
> width       ::=  integer
> precision   ::=  integer
> type        ::=  "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" | "o" | "s" | "x" | "X" | "%"
> ```

Breaking the above format down then:

```
fill: <empty>
align: <  # left
sign: <not specified>
width: 15
precision: 2
type: `f`
```

Demo:

```
>>> "{0:>15.2f}".format(1464.1000000000001)
'        1464.10'
```

Note that for numbers, the default alignment is to the right, so the `>` could be omitted.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I just got around the problem myself by doing two separate iterations of .format(), and it was horrible, this is much more elegant. I couldn't find anything on google about this, so thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
"{0:15.2f}".format(1464.1000000000001)
```

I always find this site useful for this stuff:

https://pyformat.info/